# Difference in usage and nuance between "exutoire", "défouloir" and "soupape"?

Tags: sens, usage

> L'équitation, c'est mon **exutoire**.
>
> L'équitation, c'est mon **défouloir**.
>
> L'équitation, c'est ma **soupape**.
>
> L'équitation, c'est ma **soupape de sécurité**.

When used figuratively, these three seem to be essentially interchangeable on the surface, but I can’t help feeling that their usage is somewhat different. And what about their register?

Answer (score 2):

- *L'équitation, c'est mon exutoire.* Formal, literary
- *L'équitation, c'est mon défouloir.* Colloquial, spoken French
- *L'équitation, c'est ma soupape.* Unheard
- *L'équitation, c'est ma soupape de sécurité.* Rare

Answer (score 0):

*Exutoire* is very literary. I don't recommend using it orally.

*Défouloir* is colloquial and common. It's the most common of the ones you gave. I recommend using this one.

*soupape* and *soupape de sécurité* are a little too imaged to be used regularly. Once in a while when you really want to be figurative, maybe.

You could also use *décompresser*, as in :

> L'équitation, ça me permet de décompresser.

Comment: It's been a little while, bro! Your "décompresser" phrasing got me thinking: Does the use of the two "me"s sound just fine? "L'équitation, ça **me** permet de **me** détendre." It's just that after saying "**me** permettre", I wonder if it is better to avoid using another *pronominal* "**me** détendre"?

Comment: @Alone-zee Yes it's been a while, check your mail ;). And yes, it's perfectly fine to use two *me*s in a row. You could even say "*Me doucher, ça me permet de me détendre*"

Comment: Just checked them now! Grasping the nuances in register is tricky, only because (!!) dictionaries do not delve deeply enough into this crucial aspect of a language, alas. For instance, I suppose you detect some difference in register between the following two phrasings, but "présumer" in this specific sense is not tagged as formal or anything, so everything remains a mystery register-wise until someone points out the difference for me! ;) "Il se fait une trop haute idée de lui-même." vs "Il présume trop de lui-même."

Comment: @Alone-zee Well a lot of stuff about language is not in any books, or won't be taught to you before you stumble upon it and you look it up. I agree that register in French is pretty hard, but that's one of the things that should be integrated by speaking and listening to French a lot.